DotMin.Sync when trying to filter it does not give an error but ignores the filter
I'm using a very interesting package to sync between SQL Server.
As it's something simple, "Download Only", it behaves well and quickly.
Now I need to create a filter - something like
FROM Table_Name 
WHERE tenantID = @myVariable

I'm following the documentation here:
https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/Filters.html
Apparently the logic is simple and perfect, but I can't run the filter, it syncs but doesn't filter
I have several tables and I want to create a filter, where the tenantID column (FK) is equal to my GUID variable value.
For example:
var setup = new SyncSetup("dbo.Tennants", "dbo.Devices", "dbo.Audios", et cetera...)

setup.Tables["dbo.Tennants"].SyncDirection = SyncDirection.DownloadOnly;
setup.Tables["dbo.Devices"].SyncDirection = SyncDirection.DownloadOnly;
setup.Tables["dbo.Audios"].SyncDirection = SyncDirection.DownloadOnly;

Here the filters start:
var filterTenants = new SetupFilter("Tenants");
filterTenants.AddParameter("TenantId", DbType.Guid); 
filterTenants.AddWhere("TenantId", "Tenants", "TenantId");
setup.Filters.Add(filterTenants);

var filterDevices = new SetupFilter("Devices");
filterDevices.AddParameter("TenantId", DbType.Guid);
filterDevices.AddWhere("TenantId", "Devices", "TenantId");
setup.Filters.Add(filterDevices);

var filterAudios = new SetupFilter("Audios");
filterAudios.AddParameter("TenantId", DbType.Guid);
filterAudios.AddWhere("TenantId", "Audios", "TenantId");
setup.Filters.Add(filterAudios);

I've already tried sending the DbType.Guid type as the TableName ("TenantId", "Audios");
Here I define the created parameter called TenantID for my C# variable _myTenantId
var parameters = new SyncParameters
{
    { "TenantId", _myTenantId }
};

and at the end I execute:
var result = await agent.SynchronizeAsync(setup, parameters, progress);

Of course the code is much larger, error handling, etc., but I don't believe that this influences it.
It synchronizes all TenantIDs and not the one in my variable _myTenantId.
I made a working example to test this problem

Create 2 SQL Server databases (Master and Local)
Enable Change Tracking Create seed by tenantId create seed by random data
Run the Sync database by dotmin creating the filter by tenant
It does the sync but with all the data (Random and by tenant) I wanted the local database to have only by TenantId == appSettings.jon

https://github.com/dorathoto/POC_DotMim.Sync.Sample

TYPO alert: it's a tenant - not a "tennant" .....

I discovered that you can't send the schema name along with it. Even though it's stated in the documentation.
instead of:
setup.Tables["dbo.Tennants"].SyncDirection = SyncDirection.DownloadOnly;

the correct one:
setup.Tables["Tennants"].SyncDirection = SyncDirection.DownloadOnly;

Subtle, but the error didn't show this, I discovered it through the author's own answer.
https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync/issues/1256
